# why is setAnimationDidStopSelector discouraged?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i saw the following in apples documentation on setAnimationDidStopSelector:

"Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. If you are using the block-based animation methods, you can include your delegate’s end code directly inside your block."

I tried adding what I was going to put inside the animation stop delegate inside the animation block, but the animation doesn't look the same as when i used setAnimationDidStopSelector.

What is the reason for discouraging the use of setAnimationDidStopSelector?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are lots of APIs that get deprecated in Cocoa Touch. The framework is fairly young and Apple is still tweaking the underlying code. When it is phrased as in your question it probably means "we are going to put all our effort into making block animations perfect, setAnimationDidStopSelector will at some time in the future be deprecated - do yourself a favor and stop using it now".

It sounds weird that your animation behaves different? Have you done it like this?

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay: 0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
             aView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Do your setAnimationDidStopSelector stuff here!
        }];
```

Comment: blocks are the way to go, I've always found the old style class methods wonky at best.  +1