# iphone Animation in SplashScreen

Tags: ios, animation, splash-screen

I successfully created an animation for splash screen with this code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
AnimationimageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash1.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash2.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash3.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash4.png"], nil];

[AnimationimageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
AnimationimageView.animationDuration=3;
[AnimationimageView startAnimating];
```

I connected this code with my storyBoard.

My question is how I can know if the animation is finished in order to pass to the other view.

Comment: accept the answer if it is help you.do not say thanks as an answer.

Comment: @Android0077 You should up-vote the answer/answers that was/were helpful to your problem, and also you should select the best answer among all the provided answer as `Accepted`. You should keep this habit for all the questions that you ask and also other Question/Answers that you read and find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this code

call this function in viewDidLoad

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(gotoNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

create a method

```
-(void)gotoNextView
{
// move to next view code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` like this:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop: finished: context: )];
```

And implement the selector:

```
- (void)animationDidStop: (NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context: (void *)context 
{
    //your code here.
}
```

However based on Apple Docs:

> You can specify an animation delegate in cases where you want to
>   receive messages when the animation starts or stops. After calling
>   this method, you should call the setAnimationWillStartSelector: and
>   setAnimationDidStopSelector: methods as needed to register appropriate
>   selectors. By default, the animation delegate is set to nil.
>
> You primarily use this method to set the delegate for animation blocks
>   created using the begin/commit animation methods. Calling this method
>   from outside an animation block does nothing.
>
> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. If you are
>   using the block-based animation methods, you can include your
>   delegate’s start and end code directly inside your block.

However Apple is NOT suggesting a different solution *if* you're not using blocks; and also in [The Elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TheElements/Listings/Classes_AtomicElementViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419-Classes_AtomicElementViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10) sample code, which [is upgraded for iOS 6.0 SDK, and updated to adopt current best practices for Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), Apple still uses `setAnimationDidStopSelector:`.

However there's a good explanation of this discouragement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267415/why-is-setanimationdidstopselector-discouraged), suggesting that it's probably because Apple is going to improve block animations much better, and may deprecate `setAnimationDidStopSelector` in the future.

So if you want to use blocks instead of the current approach, do the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay: 0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
             aView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Do your setAnimationDidStopSelector stuff here!
        }];
```

Comment: As per Apple, Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. If you are using the block-based animation methods, you can include your delegate’s end code directly inside your block.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this @NagaMalleshMaddali?

Comment: Please check this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDidStopSelector:

Comment: Right @NagaMalleshMaddali. Thanks for pointing it out; however it's not deprecated, it's just *discouraged* for the moment. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Check it out now @NagaMalleshMaddali! (:

Comment: i appreciate your answer for refering after devoted by @NagaMalleshMaddali ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267415/why-is-setanimationdidstopselector-discouraged

Answer (score 2):

I'd take on another approach and use the block-based solutions now supported by UIView. Specifically the method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

can achieve what you want with some modifying of your code. See the reference here [link to apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)

Answer (score -1):

try + (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector

Comment: As per Apple, Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. If you are using the block-based animation methods, you can include your delegate’s end code directly inside your block.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Most probably it will be deprecated as it is discouraged to use.